# Trouble with Cookie Handling in Express.js - Unable to Set Cookies

Tags: node.js, express

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm relatively new to programming and currently working on a web application using Node.js and Express. I've encountered an issue with cookie handling in my server, and after trying to debug it myself, I still can't figure out what's going wrong.

Problem:
I'm attempting to set a cookie in my Express.js server, but for some reason, it's not working as expected. The res.cookie method is being called, but the cookie isn't getting set in the browser. Additionally, when I try to read the cookie on subsequent requests, it's not being recognized.

Background:
I've provided the relevant portions of my code below. The application involves user account creation, and I'm trying to set a session cookie upon successful account creation.

Request for Assistance:
As a beginner, I might be missing something fundamental. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code and provide guidance on what might be causing this cookie handling issue.

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')
const app = express()
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
const db = new PouchDB('accounts');
const google_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
const secret_key = "x"
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const jwt_key = 'x'
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

app.use(cookieParser());
// error messages
const invalid_name = "Please enter a valid name!"
const invalid_email = "Please enter a valid email address!"
const invalid_password = "Your password must contain 8 characters!"
const invalid_confirm = "Your password must match!"
const invalid_check = "Please accept our Terms of Use!"
const invalid_captcha = "Please complete our human verification!"
const email_used = "The email address is already in use. Please use a different email."
//

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// database
db.createIndex({
  index: { fields: ['email'], unique: true }
});
function isEmailUsed(email) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.find({
      selector: { email: email },
      fields: ['_id'],
      limit: 1
    }).then(result => {
      // If a document is found, the email is already used
      resolve(result.docs.length > 0);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error checking email:', error);
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
async function printAllDocs() {
  try {
    const result = await db.allDocs({ include_docs: true });
    result.rows.forEach(row => {
      console.log(row.doc);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching documents:', error);
  }
}

// Call the function to print all documents
printAllDocs();
// Sign Up handler
app.post("/createaccount",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.cookies.auth);
    var reqData = req.body
    const user_ip = req.ip
    const email = reqData.email
    const firstname = reqData['first-name']
    const lastname = reqData['last-name']
    const password = reqData.password
    // we need to double check client's informations.
    //checking captcha
    const captcha_data = {
      secret:secret_key,
      response:reqData.token,
      remoteip:user_ip
    }
    console.log(user_ip);
    function senderror(msg,code){
      res.status(code).json({message:msg})
    }
    request.post(
      google_url,
      {headers:{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},body: new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(captcha_data)).toString()},
       (err,xmlres,body)=>{
        const res_captcha = JSON.parse(body)
        const is_success = res_captcha.success
        if (is_success){
          // TODO: check if the email is already used.
          isEmailUsed(email).then( (result) =>{
            if (result){
              // email is already used
              senderror(email_used,409)
            }else{
              // user is valid: create account, redirect him to that account while creating a cookie
              const user = {
                email: email,
                firstname: firstname,
                lastname: lastname,
                password: password,
                verified: false,
                creation_date: Date.now(),
                sessions: {['0']:{ip:user_ip,time:Date.now()}},
              }
              db.post(user).then((result)=>{
                // account successfully created
                const userid = result.id
                // creating a token
                const session_id = "0"
                const token = jwt.sign({session_id,userid},jwt_key)
                // account is done
                // user has to verify his account 
                // TODO: send email to user with a verification link.
                console.log('account created with success!');
                console.log(token);
                res.status(200).cookie('session-token',token,{ maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,httpOnly: true}).json({success:true})
              }).catch((error)=>{
                console.error(error)
                senderror("Internal error!",404)
              })
            }
          }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error)
          })
        }else{
          // user was not valid
          senderror(invalid_captcha,401)
        }
      }
    )
})



// Sign In handler
app.listen(4202)
```

What happens is when I click "Sign Up" with correct informations, it creates an account appropriately but doesn't seem to be adding a cookie.

Comment: How are the requests being sent to your server that are missing the cookies?  Are they coming straight from the browser as a page load or a form submit or are they coming from Javascript in the web page or are they coming from some other code that isn't browser-based?  Can you show the client-side?

Comment: Several other observations.  `.status(200)` is unnecessary.  The default status is already 200.  Your `return new Promise(...)` where you already have a promise from the db is an anti-pattern.  Just do `return db.find()` and control the resolved value or reject from within the `.then()` and `.catch()`.  There is no need to make a new promise there.

Comment: Also, how are you evaluating that the cookie isn't set in the browser?  Did you actually look in the dev tools in the browser?  My guess is that you are sending this request with client-side Javascript and aren't using the `withCredentials: true` option so `fetch()` isn't sending the promise to your server.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you very much, I enabled `xhr.withCredentials = true` and it worked!!

Comment: You should not be using the xhr interface (that's ancient).  Use the `fetch()` interface.  Start out in your programming using the modern interfaces and the ones that are promise based.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `withCredentials: true` option when making your ajax call tso tell it that it should send cookies with the request.